# Shared folder suddenly not visible for Windows 10

Tags: airport, file-sharing

I have this shared folder on macOS and it was visible for a long time for Windows. Suddenly not. And somehow my mac has become invisible for my windows machine. What can be the problem? I am not a very technical person.

Comment: Given your description, it can be anything, starting with the Mac being turned off.

Comment: What did you change on your Mac since the last time it worked? New OS version installed for instance?

Comment: I think there was a macOS update a couple of days ago. Also I had current faults. And because of that the power supply of my Airport extreme died. How can I start from scratch again ? I have these folders shared and I have set that guest users can share my folders

Comment: You really need to provide more details, especially if you've had problems with your network setup (e.g. the dead Airport extreme you mention in your previous comment). That on its own could be the cause of your problem, but since you don't mention it in your question I assume you have reason for thinking it's something else causing the problem. Please explain your network setup (especially between the Mac and Windows machine). Also, what version of macOS are you running?

Comment: i have a local area network with two diskstations, a mac and a windows machine. the disk stations are accessible from both the windows and the mac. but the mac is invisible for the windows machine. network settings have not changed. how can I create a complete new situation and start with making the mac visible again ?